# How to use visual studio and google maps and show the map in full screen ? and when using live server to run how to open the same tab in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, visual-studio-code

css

```
#map
{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

java

```
function initMap() {
    // The location of Uluru
    const uluru = { lat: 32.1582615544072, lng: 34.89155037133181 };

    // The map, centered at Uluru
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: uluru,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    });

    const rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map,
        bounds: {
            north: uluru.lat - 0.005,
            south: uluru.lat + 0.005,
            west: uluru.lng - 0.005,
            east: uluru.lng + 0.005,
        },
      });
}
  
  window.initMap = initMap;
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google Maps Api</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

</head>
<body>
<h1>Google Maps</h1>
<div id="map"></div>

<script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
//<script src="/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried in the CSS file code to change the height from 500px to 100% so both height and width are 100% and then it is full screen but it's not browsing to the map at all. with 500px in the height it's working but I want to be able to change it to full screen or a size that is close to full screen.

the second problem is in the visual studio code application I make right click on the index.html file and then select: Open with Live Server, the problem is that each time I'm doing it it's opening a new tab in the edge browser.  is there a way to make that it will use the same tab in the browser and will not open a new tab each time?

Tried to change the height from 500px to 100% but then it's not browsing not getting to the google map at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I tried your code on a jsbin and it seems to work just fine: https://jsbin.com/corabemumu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Java ≠ Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I tried running your code on jsbin and I can see that it is working fine

Here's the link (I commented this on the question already): https://jsbin.com/corabemumu/edit?html,css,js,output

So I assumed that the main cause would probably be on how you are using the VSCode.

I was able to reproduce the issue by cloning a simple map sample from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple#clone-sample) (Make sure that you have node installed on your computer).

```
git clone -b sample-map-simple https://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples.git
cd js-samples
npm i
npm start
```

In this case, you can just copy paste the localhost link or right click on the `index.html`. I don't understand why you would like to have the live server open on the same browser tab since once you have opened a live server on your browser you don't need to repeatedly open another one whenever you edit your code, you can just refresh the tab.

Going back to your issue, I just edited the sample map's content with your own code and confirmed that the map is not appearing.

### There were 2 possible reason why your map is not appearing

1. As I'm not sure how you named your Javascript file, it could be that the name on your javascript file is not the same with your `<script src="/*Javascript_file_name_here*"></script>`. As I can see on your code, you have put there `app.js` so just make sure that it's the same.
2. Another reason would be because you have not set the height of your `body`, that's why setting the height of your `#map` to 100% does not make your map to appear. as per the documentation, you should set your `style.css` file like this:

   ```
   /* 
    * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
    * that contains the map. 
    */
   #map {
     height: 100%;
   }

   /* 
    * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
    */
   html,
   body {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }
   ```

I just made sure that both is fixed and I can see that your code is working on VSCode now.

*P.S. I can see on your question that you have labeled your **javascript** file with "java". Please take note that Java and Javascript are totally different programming languages.*

Hope this helps!